# React.createClass is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Создал проект командой `create-react-app test`. Затем отредактировал файл `App.js`:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        var Hello = React.createClass({
            render: function() {
                return (<h1>Hello World</h1>);
            }
        });
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <header className="App-header">
                  <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
                  <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
                </header>
                <Hello/>
                <p className="App-intro">
                  To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
                </p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

При запуске ошибка `TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_react___default.a.createClass is not a function`, хотя в туториалах не ругается на `React.createClass()`

Comment: Читать [ТУТ](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/04/07/react-v15.5.0.html#migrating-from-reactcreateclass)

Answer (score 1):

Вы в методе render класса App пытаетесь создать класс Hello. Его нужно вынести на уровень класса App. И лучше воспользоваться более современным способом создания класса
class Hello extends Component{}